# Gluon on iPhone telling NoSuchMethodError

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

Next thing:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
java.util.Date.from(Ljava/time/Instant;)Ljava/util/Date;
```

its running on desktop but not deployed on mobile..

Thanks for any suggestion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the `java.util.Date` class works on mobile (Android and iOS).  However there a few cases that are not available.

On Android or iOS if you try

```
Date date = Date.from(Instant.now());
```

that refers to the Java 8 static method `Date.from(Instant)`, you'll get the exception you mentioned:

```
W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method from(Ljava/time/Instant;)Ljava/util/Date; in class Ljava/util/Date; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.Date' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
```

To solve this issue, you can use the usual constructor instead, which is in turn what the static method uses:

```
// Android, iOS
Date date = new Date(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()));
```

Alternatively you can use the new `java.time` package.

Comment: Thank you again!! Is there a doc pointing out which are not available maybe?

Comment: Check the documentation for JavaFXPorts [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/) and for Gluon Mobile [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.1.0/). Also check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538796/which-java-distribution-level-does-gluon-mobile-javafx-expose-for-ios-and-a).