# NoSuchMethodError - no static method comparing (java/util/Comparator)

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile

I'm sorting a `List` from `java.util`, with Gluon, on an Android Device. The application is not getting compiled for iOS (not enough ram) even with 8GB allocated, but that's another issue.

`classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.4'`

`compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.2'`

`jfxmobile version = '3.2.4'`

This line which causes the crash:

`highscoreList.sort(comparing(Highscore::getScore).reversed()); //#89`

```
03-22 09:42:14.709 27312 27337 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
03-22 09:42:14.709 27312 27337 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.x.pacman, PID: 27312
03-22 09:42:14.709 27312 27337 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method comparing(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/util/Comparator; in class Ljava/util/Comparator; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.Comparator' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
03-22 09:42:14.709 27312 27337 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.x.pacman.HighscoreUtil.readHighscoreList(HighscoreUtil.java:89)
```

I began searching and I found [this post about NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788266/gluon-on-iphone-telling-nosuchmethoderror), so I tried to do the following, but alas it still crashes, and now I'm out of ideas:

```
Comparator<Highscore> comparator = new Comparator<Highscore>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Highscore highscore1, Highscore highscore2) {
        return highscore1.getScore() - highscore2.getScore();
    }
};

highscoreList.sort(comparator); //#97


03-22 11:30:48.836 16547 16570 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
03-22 11:30:48.836 16547 16570 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.kaufland.pacman.HighscoreUtil.readHighscoreList(HighscoreUtil.java:97)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [`Comparator#comparing()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function%3C?%20super%20T,%20?%20extends%20U%3E)) and [`List#sort(Comparator)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) were added in API level 24 and your device is probably running a lower API level.

You'll probably have better luck with [`Collections#sort()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)) that has been there since API level 1.

Comment: `Collections.sort(highscoreList, (highscore1, highscore2) -> highscore2.getScore() - highscore1.getScore());` solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference. I got this error when using http://www.vavr.io/ collections.

I called the function [toSortedSet()](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.1/io/vavr/Value.html#toSortedSet--) of a [LinkedHashSet](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.1/io/vavr/collection/LinkedHashSet.html). This function tries to call [Comparator.naturalOrder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder()) which needs API Level 24.

If you must use a lower API level, just use the overloaded [toSortedSet(Comparator)](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.1/io/vavr/Value.html#toSortedSet-java.util.Comparator-) function and pass a suitable comparator.