# javafxports javafx.scene.media.Media file path after build

Tags: javafxports

So I was trying to convert one of my java fx projects to an android app using gluon. It's a scene where it implements image viewer etc. So I expected the files to all be accessible, however upon using the Media no matter where I put the file or put as the path, I can't get the app to detect the .wav file in my project. I was wondering if I could get some assistance on where to put my .wav file and what to use as the URl for the Media("") portion of the code.

```
package com.junhong.faceclickb;

import com.gluonhq.charm.down.Services;
import com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.VideoService;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Graphics extends Application {
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    ToolBar toolbar = new ToolBar();
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Score score = new Score(0);
    Text generation = new Text("Score: " + score.getScore());
    private Animate animate = new Animate();
    private ImageView img = new ImageView();
    Face face;
    Bounds bounds = borderPane.getBoundsInLocal();
    double dx = 5;
    double dy = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    public Parent createContent() {
        // // top
        HBox top = new HBox();
        top.getChildren().add(generation);
        borderPane.setTop(top);
        // face
        face = new Face("normalFace.png");
        EventHandler myMouseEvent = new myMouseEvent();
        img.setImage(new Image(face.getImgName()));
        img.setOnMousePressed(myMouseEvent);
        borderPane.setCenter(img);
        return borderPane;
    }

    private void setRandomDx() {
        dx = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
    }

    private void setRandomDy() {
        dy = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
    }

    // private void directionMove(ImageView img, double speed, double direction) {
    // dx = face.getXValue() + Math.cos(direction * (Math.PI / 180)) * speed;
    // dy = face.getYValue() + Math.sin(direction * (Math.PI / 180)) * speed;
    // moveImg(img, dx, dy);
    //
    // }

    private void speedImg(ImageView img, double dx, double dy) {
        borderPane.getChildren().remove(img);
        face.setXValue(face.getXValue() + dx);
        face.setYValue(face.getYValue() + dy);
        img.setX(face.getXValue());
        img.setY(face.getYValue());
        borderPane.getChildren().add(img);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Face Clicker");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
        Services.get(VideoService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
            service.getPlaylist().add("china.wav");
            service.play();
        });

    }

    class myMouseEvent implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                score.addScore(1, 1);
                generation.setText("Score: " + score.getScore());
                // if(Math.random()*5 == 1){
                // face.setRage();
                // }
                // if(face.getRage()){
                setRandomDx();
                setRandomDy();
                // }

                animate.start();

            }

        }

    }

    private class Animate extends AnimationTimer {
        private long n = 100_000_000;
        private long last = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (now - last >= n) {
                // what happens when animation happens
                if (face.getXValue() + img.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2 > borderPane.getWidth()) {
                    dx = -dx;
                }
                if (face.getXValue() - img.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2 <= (-1) * borderPane.getWidth() / 2) {
                    dx = -dx;
                }
                if (img.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2 + face.getYValue() >= borderPane.getHeight() / 2) {
                    dy = -dy;
                }
                if (face.getYValue() - img.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2 <= (-1) * borderPane.getHeight() / 2) {
                    dy = -dy;
                }
                speedImg(img, dx, dy);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is the full log cat:

```
09-22 16:28:44.475 29162 29167 I art     : Do partial code cache collection, code=26KB, data=30KB
09-22 16:28:44.475 29162 29167 I art     : After code cache collection, code=25KB, data=30KB
09-22 16:28:44.475 29162 29167 I art     : Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
09-22 16:28:44.634 29162 29185 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method double javafx.scene.text.TextFlow.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(javafx.scene.Node, javafx.geometry.Insets) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javafx.scene.layout.Region
09-22 16:28:44.634 29162 29185 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method double javafx.scene.text.TextFlow.computeChildPrefAreaWidth(javafx.scene.Node, javafx.geometry.Insets) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javafx.scene.layout.Region
09-22 16:28:44.634 29162 29185 I System.out: 0.0,0.0
09-22 16:28:44.635  1241  3128 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2361600  uid : 1000  pid : 1241  tag : APP_LAUNCH@CPU_MIN@6
09-22 16:28:44.636 29162 29185 W art     : Class javafx.scene.image.Image failed lock verification and will run slower.
09-22 16:28:44.644 29162 29185 W art     : Class com.sun.javafx.iio.ImageStorage failed lock verification and will run slower.
09-22 16:28:44.734 29162 29185 W art     : Class javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerPaintListener failed lock verification and will run slower.
09-22 16:28:44.737 29162 29185 W art     : Before Android 4.1, method void com.sun.javafx.scene.transform.TransformUtils$ImmutableTransform.ensureCanTransform2DPoint() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javafx.scene.transform.Transform
09-22 16:28:44.748 29162 29185 W art     : Class com.sun.javafx.text.GlyphLayout failed lock verification and will run slower.
09-22 16:28:44.778 29162 29185 I DefaultVideoService: Playlist changed: { [china.wav] added at 0 }
09-22 16:28:44.778 29162 29185 I DefaultVideoService: file: china.wav already exists
09-22 16:28:44.779 29162 29185 I AndroidVideoService: Creating new MediaPlayer for china.wav
09-22 16:28:44.785 29162 29185 I MediaPlayer: Need to enable context aware info
09-22 16:28:44.785 29162 29185 V MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
09-22 16:28:44.785 29162 29185 E MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
09-22 16:28:44.785 29162 29185 E MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
09-22 16:28:44.785 29162 29185 V MediaPlayer: constructor
09-22 16:28:44.788 29162 29185 V MediaPlayer: setListener
09-22 16:28:44.801   757   757 V MediaPlayerService: Create new media retriever from pid 29162
09-22 16:28:44.805 29162 29185 W System.err: Exception in Application start method
09-22 16:28:44.833  1241  1699 I qti_sensors_hal: processReportInd: Accel - X: 0.893 Y: 1.211 Z: 9.90
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX on mobile doesn't support media. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36543260/3956070) for current supported features.

But that doesn't mean you can't use the native player from your device.

Recently, [Charm Down](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/charm-down/) (an open source library to access the device and its hardware features using a uniform, platform-independent API) added a Video Service.

You can see a short post on how to use it [here](http://gluonhq.com/new-gluon-charm-services-part/).

Basically you'll need to include the `video` plugin in your build:

```
// build.gradle
jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.6.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'video'
    }
}
```

place the audio/video files in the resource folder `/src/main/resoures`, or provide a valid URL, and then you'll be able to use the service:

```
Services.get(VideoService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
    service.getPlayList().add("myAudio.wav");
    service.play(); 
});
```

The audio doesn't add any visible control (MediaView), it plays in background. You can add some buttons to play/pause/stop the audio.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I've added the plugin to the build.gradle but I can't seem to utilize the service as the code cannot find the VideoService.class, do I need to do something else to use the service?

Comment: After modifying the build file, you need to reload the project, so the new dependencies are downloaded. If you open the project, check under dependencies if you find the charm-down-plugin-* jars.

Comment: Sorry about all the questions I'm still a novice with coding, I was able to manually add the video plugin into the dependencies. and the code does now compile, however the code doesn't seem to want to execute the service. This message pops up: SEVERE: javafx.platform is not defined. Desktop will be assumed by default. While the rest of the code runs, when the service is called upon its as if the program simply freezes.

Comment: Note the service is only available on mobile (Android and iOS), so you should test it on your device. Anyway, it shouldn't freeze on desktop, as `Services.get(VideoService.class).ifPresent()` won't be executed.

Comment: hmm when called upon, it simply goes to a black screen on my android the log cat spews out this :
`09-22 15:44:05.565 11733 11753 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-22 15:44:05.565 11733 11753 W System.err:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
...
09-22 15:44:05.565 11733 11753 W System.err:  ... 1 more
09-22 15:44:05.565 11733 11753 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
09-22 15:44:05.565 11733 11753 W System.err:  at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(Native Method)`

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some relevant code and the stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added the code and the log cat my android device returned upon opening the code.

Comment: Add this `System.setProperty("com.gluonhq.charm.down.debug", "true");` before the call to the service, to have a more verbose output. Deploy again and post the relevant output.

Comment: That's not the full logcat. If you can't post everything relevant (too long), could you add a link with it?

Comment: I made a google doc with the full log cat. Thank you for all your help. :)
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KryWIqvF2Nc4t90QFGF15eTI_oQaXDNoe8dzfy-X40I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it seems the audio file is wrong. Can you double check that you have place it under `/src/main/resources`? Can you play it on your desktop? Can you try with another file, an mp3?